# A rule in the recursive clauses governing type formation in a higher order logic

Tags: logic, type-theory, higher-order-logic

My question regards the theory of types, as augmented and formalised by Richard Montague.

On page 10 of Gallin's "Intensional and Higher order modal logic"

- https://www.elsevier.com/books/intensional-and-higher-order-modal-logic/gallin/978-0-7204-0360-2 [1975]

Gallin formulates thus the set of types of $IL$, Montague's intensional logic:

> $Types$. Let $e , t , s$ be any three objects, none of which is an
>   ordered pair. The set of types of $IL$ is the smallest set $T$ satisfying:
>
> $(i) \hspace{0.4cm} e \thinspace, \hspace{0.2cm} t \in T ,$
>
> $(ii) \hspace{0.4cm} \alpha, \beta \in T$ imply $(\alpha,\beta) \in T ,$
>
> $(iii) \hspace{0.4cm} \alpha \in T$ implies $(s,a) \in T .$

Gallin remarks that "objects of type $e$ will be possible entities or individuals,
objects of type $t$ will he truth-values, objects of type $(\alpha,\beta)$
will be functions from objects of type $\alpha$ to objects of type $\beta$, and objects of type $(s,a)$ will be functions from indices to objects of type $\alpha$".

Why does Gallin say that $e, t, s$ can be "any three objects", given that he specifies what objects belonging to these types are (as individuals, truth values and indices). What is achieved by saying that $e, t, s$ can be any objects? Why must they not be ordered pairs, as he requires?

Answer (score 1):

Types are not sets of the "objects" that have those types, they are effectively symbols and pieces of syntax to which we have a relation, the typing judgment, that associates "objects" to these symbolic expressions. We often think of types as codes that can be *interpreted* as sets or more generally objects of an appropriately structured category. That is, since types are just (inductively defined) pieces of syntax, it's straightforward to write a recursive function that maps types to sets or into categories.

The restriction on $e$, $t$, and $s$ to not be ordered pairs is just so that they aren't confused with the function types. This is mostly an artifact of the set-theoretic encoding of the structure of types. The formulation "the smallest set such that the following closure conditions hold" is a set-theoretic way of describing an inductively defined structure. Nowadays, most descriptions of type theory would use a notation more like: $$\alpha, \beta ::= \mathtt{e}\mid\mathtt{t}\mid \alpha\to\beta\mid\mathtt{s}\to\alpha$$ where $\mathtt{e}$, $\mathtt{t}$, and $\mathtt{s}$ are intended to be symbols and the types are generated from this expression like you would generate sentences from a context-free grammar. In programming languages/proof assistants, an inductive type declaration would be used, e.g. in Haskell:

```
data Types = Entities              
           | TruthValues           
           | Functions Types Types 
           | Indexed Types
```

Here `Entities`, and `TruthValues` are just symbols and the whole type is essentially just a tree with either binary or unary branching nodes with leaves labelled by `Entities` or `TruthValues`.

There's really nothing gained by allowing $e$, $t$, and $s$ to be "any" objects. (Presumably, they are also intended to be distinct...) You could require them to be the numbers $0$, $1$, and $2$ say. The point is that the only thing we require of them is that they are distinguishable from each other and from ordered pairs so that we can tell which "case" in the inductive structure we're in.

Comment: You say that types "are effectively symbols and pieces of syntax to which we have a relation, the typing judgment, that associates "objects" to these symbolic expressions." But this phrase "typing judgement", is typical of post-Church, post-Montague formulations of type theory (Martin Lof, etc). I'm not aware of any such concept of a "typing judgement" in Church or Montague, although they may be implicit in their theories.

Comment: Also, if types are just pieces of syntax, then this would not seem to convey what is meant by saying, as we may want to say in a Montagovian style semantics, that a constant $John'$ is $of$ type $e$. Here we are saying something semantic: that "$John'$" denotes an individual, So how can types be purely syntactic?

Comment: I definitely am using modern terms and perspectives on these concepts, but I don't see anything that makes me view them as anything but clarifications of what is being done here. What I'm suggesting is that you have a (class) function (or better a functor) $[\![-]\!]:\mathsf{Type}\to\mathbf{Set}$ which is recursively defined. You can the say for the individual $j$ that "John'" denotes, $j\in[\![\mathtt e]\!]$, but $\mathtt e$ is the type, not $[\![\mathtt e]\!]$. Purely syntactically, we can just have a relation $\mathsf{of}(\text{"John'"},\mathtt e)$. We can extend $[\![-]\!]$ to join these.

Comment: That said, all this is going beyond the specific question you asked. The quoted definition is a set-theoretic rendition of an inductively defined structure and, with the exception of the first paragraph of my answer, this is what I'm discussing. It is independent of what Gallin goes on to use this definition for. (It's also possible that there is some clashing of terminology between linguistics and model theory, and the object-language and meta-language going on here.)